# Can I have shortcuts for applications in the upper panel?

Tags: unity, panel

I want to have a quick launch button for the command `xkill` (Skype sometimes starts using all my ram and I have to kill it.) in my upper panel.

Is this possible in 11.10 with Unity? I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, the top panel is a menu bar not a place to put shortcuts, you can put xkill on the launcher though.